# Error: "type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'" when mapping a Dart Map

Tags: dart

I have a map structured like so:

```
Map<dynamic, dynamic> optionsMap = {1: true, 2: false, ..., "totalCount": 1};
```

I explicitly declared the values as dynamic to avoid Dart's intelligent typing, even though it should handle this and make it dynamic.

I'm going to map it to provide a `Map` with the ending structure:

```
{1:{index1Name:index1Value}, 2:{index2Name:index2Value}...}
```

When trying to map this `Map`, using

```
Map optionsMap = optionsState.map(
        (dynamic key, dynamic value) => MapEntry(key, [options[key], value]));
```

I get the following error:

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

I never strong typed an int. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the type of the `options` variable? If it is a list, the error may be caused by `MapEntry(key, [options[key], value])` within the map function running at

```
options['totalCount']
```

Comment: Thanks, Jerry! That was it. I was using it as a Map instead of a list, which was fine, until a `String` came along.